# getting an error message when trying to run django project locally

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a project locally.  I cloned the repo and installed django and set up a virtual environment but when I run the command "python manage.py runserver" in my virtual environment I'm getting this message " .env doesn't exist.  If you're not configuring your environment seperately create one"  I checked and the .env file is in the directory that my virtual environment is in so I'm not sure why it's saying it doesn't exist.

Comment: Did you finally solve the issue?
If yes, then you might answer your own question.
If my answer had helped you might indicate that as well or you might comment why it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the exact error message is required.

It might also help to know which repo you cloned.

Perhaps the repo requires an autoenv like file  `.env` in the same directory as the file manage.py?

You can try to create a file named '.env' in the same directory than the file manage.py

as contents just put following line

```
source /path/to/your/virtual_env/bin/activate
```

and retry

You have of course to replace `/path/to/your/virtual_env` with the actual path in which your virtualenv is located.

I also suggest to type

`source .env`
prior to calling `python manage.py runserver`

If you still have issues type `pip freeze` and check whether the expected version of django is installed.

If your repo contains a file named `requirements.txt`
then type also `pip install -r requirements.txt` and retry once more.

In any case please give more precise information if you want to be helped.

Im rather guessing here but above suggestions could solve the problem if you're lucky